# How can I correct my regex for detecting numbers

Tags: php, regex, numbers

```
[a-z\%\/\-\(\)\s]?\d{3}[a-z\%\/\-\(\)\s]?\d{3}[a-z\%\/\-\(\)\s]?\d{4}[a-z\%\/\-\(\)\s]?
```

My above regex is what I've come up with. But I need something that can detect a few more patterns of numbers, and then, once the numbers are matched, remove all other texts, letters, chars in the line but the numbers. below is my regex.

### Update

Fixed:

https://www.regex101.com/r/hT5eD9/1

Comment: Can you give an example of the "patterns of numbers" you're trying to detect?

Comment: It's in the above link. I can match some but not all. Then I need to remove everything else but the matched ones.

Comment: Phone numbers? I would try the following: `\d{3}\D?\d{3}\D?\d{4}` - 3 digits, followed by an optional non-digit character, followed by 3 more digits, followed by another optional non-digit character, followed by the last 4 digits.

Comment: thanks but how do i replace everything but the above regex?

Comment: Search for matches and build a completely new string out of those matches. Forget everything else.

Comment: uhm how do i do that? not very familiar with regex lol

Comment: Anyway I fixed the problem myself. Thanks everyone. and I used David Fabers regex

Comment: check my update . it is tested in notepad++..

Answer (score 3):

You can take this approach:

Match 1 or more non-digits that are followed by digits on either side to detect non-digits in between digits and remove them.

Using this regex:

```
(?<=\d)[^\d\n]+(?=\d)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/yL6cZ1/2)

**Code:**

```
$result = preg_replace("~(?<=\\d)[^\\d\\n]+(?=\\d)~", '', $input);
```

Comment: thanks but how do i replace everything but the above regex code?

Comment: I have already give you `preg_replace` code. What output do you expect?

Comment: where do i put this code? i am trying to do this in notepad++

Comment: You tagged your question as php and now asking how to do it in `Notepad++`? I have provided you a PHP code and a working regex demo that you can adapt anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, but I would like it in notepad++ kindly.

Comment: You can use demo link I provided and use in search/replace of Notepad++

Comment: I am not understanding it. the numbers are found in a large wall of text with other numerical values. i know to use your code in the regex find, but what do i replace with in N++?

Comment: Sorry I don't know Notepad++. If this regex worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer. And then open a question specific to `Notepad++`

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
<? 
if(is_numeric($str)){
    //str is a number
}
```

Comment: OP requires regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**  regex pattern `([^\d\s]+|\s\d{1,2}[\s\,])*(\d{3}[^\d\n]*\d{3}[^\d\n]*\d{4})*([^\d\s]+|\s\d{1,2}[\s\,])*`

You search `([^\d\s]+|\s\d{1,2}[\s\,])*(\d{3}[^\d\n]*\d{3}[^\d\n]*\d{4})*([^\d\s]+|\s\d{1,2}[\s\,])*`  and  replace with `$2` . it will works for your condition.

**Update:**

[Live demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/yL6cZ1/5)

Comment: yea but this is similar to [^0-9\n]. ur code keeps excess, unwanted numbers that are not part of phone numbers

Comment: What is your input and output sample?

Comment: https://www.regex101.com/r/yL6cZ1/4
I want to use this code, \d{3}\D?\d{3}\D?\d{4} in Notepad++ but what to replace with?